# MacBookPro 2011 GPU failure. Csrutil command will not work at all

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, macos

I am having the GPU failure issue and I'm trying to disable some kexts however i'm constantly told operation permitted.

I am following Lizardtrons video on Youtube where it seems atleast 2.2K people have had success however I'm stuck.

https://youtu.be/nFFPk3SeQbQ

I have installed Dosdudes software to automatically delete the kexts for me however it still says SIP is enabled.

I am running MacOS Sierra 10.12.6. I can add more info if needed.

I cannot for the life of me disable csrutil in terminal, safe mode or recovery mode. It says the command is not found. It is as if computer does not know the command.

However when I type in 'csrutil status' in terminal on the desktop it actually says SIP enabled.

So its recognising it on the desktop terminal but not on safe mode(cmd S) and Recovery mode (cmd R).

I have also tried internet recovery to newest install newest OS however it only promts me to install OX Lion.

I installed El Capitan onto an external HD to see if I could boot a new OS from that but when holding option key prior to boot, the only HD that comes up is the internal drive and not the external boot drive.

I am running MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

All i need to do is 'csrutil disable' so operations can be permitted.

I've been at it for 3 days now and I really don't want to give up as I've got a week off work and decided to dig this out of its death!

Any help is greatly appricieated. I am not 100% tech savy however I can adapt fast with instructions etc

Also sorry if the question is all over the place.

Comment: `csrutil` should exist in all modes (as long as you're running 10.11 or later), but should only be able to enable/disable SIP in Recovery mode. Try starting in Recovery mode, and run `sw_vers` to make sure your Recovery environment is up to date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, after typing in sw_vers it comes back with product name: mac os x. Productversion: 10.7.5. Build version 11G63.

Comment: That's too old a version to have `csrutil`. It sounds like either it's running Internet Recovery, or the Recovery partition on your computer never got properly updated. Try restarting with Command-Option-R; that [should start in the latest Recovery version your Mac can run](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904); see what `sw_vers` shows then, and if it's 10.11 or later (it should be) see if `csrutil` is available.

Comment: Ah right ok, i'll start up with that command and get back to you in 5 minutes. Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: Just checked in terminal via cmd-option-R and its still the same. Product version 10.7 5. Build version 11G63

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting an out-of-date Recovery version, but maybe you can do the change "by hand". Within the old Recovery system try running `nvram csr-active-config=0x67` ([see this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/3hv3kk/update_on_rootless_the_configuration_mechanism/cub82zd/)), then restart normally and see if SIP is disabled.

Comment: I ran the command in the recovery mode then reboot. Upon rebooting i opened terminal and typed in csrutil status and it says its still enabled

Comment: Very weird. Try resetting the NVRAM (hold Command-Option-P-R as you restart, and let it try to start up a couple of times before releasing those keys). Then start in Recover again, and try the `nvram` command.

Comment: I have just reset the NVRAM holding until the screen flashed a couple of times. Then rebooted into Recovery mode. I inputted the 'nvram' command. Should I then just reboot/restart into normal startup?

Comment: Also, is it normal that when I entered the command that nothing happened it just went to the next command line? Am i expecting a command in return or?

Comment: I restarted as normal and the SIP is still enabled. This is after resetting NVRAM holding until screen flashed a couple of times then starting recovery mode then entering the nvram command then rebooting. Still no joys..

Comment: Dang, I'm pretty much out of ideas. I think at this point I'd need to work on it in person to figure out what's going on. Sorry...

Comment: Ah no problem, I'm sure someone will hopefully help out too. I really appriciate your time pal, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just incase anyone had this same issue.

I had to use a new external HD (backed up everything onto it) and booted with that using option button.

Then erased the internal disk using disk utility and it then allowed me to do a fresh MacOS which then updated the recover software to 10.12.6 Sierra.

Which then therefore allowed me to disable csrutil in Recovery mode.